# How to get ordered products withing a date range in magento 2 programmatically?

Tags: orders, products, magento2.2.2

I want to get the products ordered within a date range for a report.

As the result, I need like, product, product type, product Qty.

I tried to load all orders and get the sum of products, it want working out.

```
$orders = $this->orderCollectionFactory->create()
        ->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('from'=>$dateFrom, 'to'=>$dateTo))
        ->addFieldToFilter('status', array('nin' => array('canceled','refund_request','refunded', 'return_exchange_request')));
```

How can I get the products count individually for each product from this collection?

Expecting result
|Product-+-type---+-Qty-|
+--------+--------+-----+
| P1     | simple | 10  |

Answer (score 0):

```
protected $itemFactory;
protected $orderFactory:

public function __construct(
  \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\ItemFactory $itemFactory,
  \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory $OrderFactory

) {
   $this->itemFactory = $itemFactory;
   $this->orderFactory = $OrderFactory;

}
```

then in your function

```
$order = $this->orderFactory->create()->getCollection()
->addFieldToFilter('status', array('nin' => array('canceled','refund_request','refunded', 'return_exchange_request')))
->addFieldToFilter('created_at', ['gteq' => $dateFrom])
->addFieldToFilter('created_at', ['lteq' => $dateTo]);
foreach($order->getAllVisibleItems() as $Items){
  $orderId = $Items->geId();
  $orderItems = $this->itemFactory->create()->getCollection()
  ->addFieldToFilter('order_id', $orderId);
  foreach($orderItems as $item){
    $qty = $item->getQtyOrdered();
    $type = $item->getProductType();
    $productId = $item->getProductId();
    //etc
  }
}
```

the data is fetched from sales_order_item table.

Comment: i am getting an error here ->addFieldToFilter('status', array('nin' => array('canceled','refund_request','refunded', 'return_exchange_request')))

Comment: Please check the edited answer!